# REST API- handling complex operations that don't fit CRUD, sever or client?

Tags: rest, api, client-server, state

Lets say I have a `DateRange` entity exposed by my API.  The database representation looks something like:

```
id: uuid,
start: date,
end: date
```

And my REST api exposes various CRUD functionality via the following endpoints:

```
/api/v1/date-ranges/ <GET, POST>
/api/v1/date-ranges/{id}/ <DELETE, PUT, PATCH>
```

These two endpoints work great if one is simply deleting or editing an entire date range (e.g.- change the end date, or delete the entire range)

However, I need to allow the client to remove a date that might be in the middle of a range (or even the entire range if `start` and `end` are the same date).  Thus this edit operation has three possible outcomes:

1. If a date from the start or end of the range is removed, the existing range entity is modified.
2. If a date in the middle of the range is removed, the existing `DateRange` entity is modified, and a new `DateRange` entity is created.
3. If the date range starts and ends on the same date (1-day range), and that date is deleted, then the existing `DateRange` entity is deleted.

These three different outcomes from a single call doesn't seem to fit the RESTful paradigm well, and I am not sure the best way to handle it.  I see a couple of possibilities:

I could use `/api/v1/date-ranges/{id}/ <PATCH>`, and pass the date to be deleted from the range.  Then it could return a body that looks like:

```
modified: {id: string, start: date, end: date}[]
deleted: {id: string}[]
created: {id: string, start: date, end: date}[]
```

Then in cases where nothing is created, it would return an empty array for `created`, likewise for `modified` and `deleted`.  This has the advantage that the API handles all of the housekeeping of keeping the state correct.  However as I mentioned before, it doesn't match the standard REST api response body.

The other option I see is to have the client handle all of the housekeeping, and make multiple calls to the API for each needed operation (e.g.- first call a PATCH operation to modify the existing entity, then if necessary call a POST operation to create a new entity).  This has the advantage of keeping things RESTful, but introduces the possibility of a broken state in the database if a second call to the API is interrupted/network loss, etc.

How are issues like this typically handled in a RESTful way?

Answer (score 0):

> How are issues like this typically handled in a RESTful way?

By working through how you would do it if your resources were "just" web pages.

1) Here's a web page; I want to make some change to it, so I click on the edit link.  That brings me to a form, which describes the data I need to include with the change.  I fill in those details, and submit the form.  The server gets the request, and figures out how to make my change happen.  In the response, I get a representation of the status of the action.

2) Here's a web page; I want to make some change to it.  So I load a copy of the representation into my preferred editor, and make the changes I want to my copy.  I then send my updated copy back to the server.  The server gets the request, and figures out how to make its copy consistent with my copy.  In the response, I get a representation of the status of the action.